# Fixing nav bar made with Flexbox to top of page, but when you scroll up nav bar becomes covered

Tags: html, css

So I created a navigation bar with flex box.  I currently have a wrapper around the  so that I can make it fixed to the top.  This functions correctly and when you load the page the nav bar looks fine.  But when you scroll up past what would be the boundaries of the page the navbar becomes covered.  How would I avoid this (I have attached images below to show what I mean).

[Before scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfdSf.png)

[After scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHFQF.png)

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
      <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="assets/logo.png"></a>
      <div class ="nav-links">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

```css
nav {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); /*background color*/
  height: 75px; /*height of navigation bar*/
  display: flex; /*activates flexbox properties*/
  align-items: center; /*uses flexbox to vertically center items*/
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8px); /*blurs background*/
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px); /*blurs background*/
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you share information about scrollable element or the element comes after wrapper? I'm curios about the relationship between them. I think the solution must be in there.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be no issue after resetting default margin and padding:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not solve the issue :/.  It's still that when you forcefully scroll up the navigation bar does what it does in the second picture.